# Debian автозагрузка и grub

Tags: debian, grub

Вообщем в debian в network/if-up.d/ попало, очень злое что то. Как через GRUB можно загрузиться без network/if-up.d/ или как можно очистить находящийся там файл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поможет любой ман по

```
google "debian grub root password reset"
```

либо [Boot Linux Grub Into Single User Mode](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grub-boot-into-single-user-mode/)

Comment: Не помогает single mode

Comment: не сингл мод, а init=/bin/bash в параметрах ядра.

Comment: ну да, должен помочь ) смысл один, получить шелл до полного инита